# Recycling : paper, plastic or aluminum, which one to choose, if only one?

Tags: recycling, environmental-impact, plastic, paper

Supposing I can focus only on one type of material to recycle, choosing from paper (card board etc), aluminum (can etc) or plastic (water bottle etc), then which choice of material will help the environment most?

https://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/green-science/paper-plastic1.htm

Comment: Why are you asking this hypothetical question? I fail to see its relevance, especially since it's so broad.

Comment: Respectfully, this is not a hypothetical question. I am asking because, I see people focusing on card board and paper recycling, but not doing recycling of Plastic bottles and aluminum. I feel paper and card board can be get recycled by itself, but Plastic and aluminum will not in 400+ years, so wanted feedback/answer from Sustainable Living.

Comment: Related: [What is the environmental impact of recycling beverage containers, by material?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/6838/3379).

Comment: I think, to @JanDoggen's point, a better question would be about the relative impact of the three different materials both as virgin products, and through recycling.

Comment: Then tell us about *I see people focusing on card board and paper recycling* to show it is not hypothetical. **Why are you asking?**. There may be far more factors at play (like availability of recycling services) that determine if people recycle or not.

Comment: Why leave out glass?

Comment: @mblakele I am specifically asking "if only one"

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is sustainability and I can only choose one, I'd choose aluminum. Aluminum is relatively cost-effective to recycle and doesn't decompose on its own. Paper is middling efficient to recycle, and decomposes on its own — eventually. Plastic is relatively inefficient to recycle, and also doesn't decompose much on its own — which means we should avoid using it wherever possible, especially if we can't recycle it for whatever reasons.

https://livegreen.recyclebank.com/column/because-you-asked/should-i-choose-plastic-aluminum-or-glass-bottles

https://earth911.com/living-well-being/recycled-beverage-containers/

https://sciencing.com/plastic-bottle-vs-aluminum-can-13636298.html